# Removing/ Undoing Database addition to Alwayson Groups

Tags: sql-server-2014, availability-groups

I am about to create a new database for an AAG group, and I want to know in case of a fall back plan where the data synchronization fails, would removing the database from the AAG and then dropping it from the primary would suffice? Please advice

Thanks!

Comment: I think we need more details of what it is your doing and what it is your are concerned about.

Comment: That's fine if you want to just completely roll back the data portion but it could fail due to many reasons.  Perhaps it's your firewall, your endpoint settings such as encryption type, it could be other things too.  Have you considered testing it on a test environment?

Comment: I am creating a template for a change request to add a new database to an existing AAG cluster. For my fallback plan to undo the whole thing in case the process doesn't work out well, I am planning to remove the database from the AAG and then drop the database. Do you think this is the right plan to go with?  We don't have a testing environment for this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to do so. However, there are some possible issues you have to consider or expect.

1. You will have at some down time in you application or web (whatever accessing the database).
2. You need to change the connection string. AOA group connection string uses the listener or AoAgroup. When you switch back, you need to use regular connection string FQDN of your server or IP of your address.
3. You might also need to remove the server from the cluster.
4. When you failover databases under your secondary server remain under no recovery state. Databases in your primary server will be online but sometimes (especially if you have really big database) if there is some transaction log left and during the failover, your database will hang up under suspect mode.

Comment: So cant the 3rd party application be installed once the new database is in the AAG group? Should the application be deployed first and do I then move the databases to the AAG? The database will not be so big. At the most 2gb in size.

Comment: It depends of what the 3rd party application is doing and configured. I can’t tell how that application is affected unless you specified what it requires, how it runs and expected configuration on the server. I don’t think there will be any problem with that, the worst case scenario, you might need to change the configuration/setting of your third party application.

Comment: Actually, the application is still not deployed to this AAG. What I actually wanted to include in the fall back plan was, in case the Initial Data Synchronization fails, what should I do. Can I include the empty db in the AAG group, perform the syncrhonization to create the secondary db and then deploy the application? What is the right way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: What is your third party application? It that a database monitoring tool?  What it the purpose of adding an empty database? I don’t see the importance adding an empty db to your AoAgroup. If you/your company have the resource, you might add additional node/server to the availability group.

Comment: No it is not a monitoring tool. It's for a Secure print application( from equitrac http://www.office.xerox.com/latest/SO1FS-05U.pdf )   which will not have much overhead. There are just 80 printers involved. There are 3 other databases in the AAG already.  They want me a create a single database in this AAG so that the print application will use it later. Can you please help me what the procedure for this would be? Thanks

Comment: Ok. This has nothing to do with neither synchronization nor backing out from AOA group. You can add a new database or use the existing one for your third party application. It depends of your preference. Anyways, even if you face synchronization fail in the future, I would not recommend you to go back to stand alone configuration, rather its easy and manageable just to figure out what cause the sync problem and just fix it.

Comment: Thank you. My question is when can I add the newly created database in the AAG? Can I do it before or after the application is deployed? Please suggest.

Comment: It doesn't matter but if I were you I would do it before the application is deployed.